# what jdbc jar to use with oracle 10.5g & jdk 1.7

Tags: java, oracle

I am able to connect to db through oracle client toad.I am using ojdbc 6 in application and jdk 1.7 but getting some java.lang.unsatisfied exception.
Can someone help me . how this can be resolved?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cConnPoolLogon(J[BI[BI[BI[BI[BIIII[Ljava/lang/String;[BI[BI[BI[BI[BI[S[B[B[J)I
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cConnPoolLogon(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.processOCIConnectionPooling(T2CConnection.java:1103)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:258)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:148)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:60)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:44)
    at oracle.jdbc.oci.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:49)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleOCIConnectionPool.getConnection(OracleOCIConnectionPool.java:244)
    at com.cisco.app.dbmigrator.migratorapp.utilities.cache.DBCacheManager.getCachedOracleConnection(DBCacheManager.java:79)
    at com.cisco.app.dbmigrator.migratorapp.service.DatabaseDetailsServiceImpl.fetchTablesDetails(DatabaseDetailsServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.cisco.app.dbmigrator.migratorapp.controller.DatabaseDetailsController.fetchTablesDetails(DatabaseDetailsController.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
```

Comment: what is the error message. "some ava.lang.unsatisfied exception" tells us exactly nothing

Comment: Add stack trace of exception to your question. And the code that connects to DB.

Comment: It seems there is no oracle 10.5g (see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)).

Comment: There is no 10.5g.  Refer to the link here for more details about supported JDBC drivers. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html